# ASP.NET Task Await Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

So, I'm just catching up on the old MVC 5 stuff now that I'm out of university.

I just looked at this [implementation](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity), its point 3. about registering a user, i noticed it used `async`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I just want a bit of clarity, I am familiar with the `async` keyword and its association with `Task` and `await`, do you **have** to use this with `Ajax` operations?

**Can** it be used with `Ajax` operations?

If so, I guess `Ajax` would be the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web code is almost always asyncronous out of the box. This is due to IIS hosting numerous threads in a pool, all listening for connections. As a result your code can run on multiple threads concurrently. `async` and `await` are a means of delegating work to a different thread pool and receiving the response when the work is done. It has nothing to do with the native-async ASP.NET pipeline, but can be used within the pipeline for additional performance gains. [Reading this might help clear it up for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have to use this with Ajax operations?

No, absolutely not. You can use synchronous code with AJAX operations (and most of the time you probably will): the client (browser) request is still asynchronous even if a server thread is blocked in the background.

> Can it be used with Ajax operations?

Yes, it can. When it's appropriate. Generally to allow long-running I/O operations to complete without blocking worker threads.

In your example, the `Register` method will be waiting for `UserManager.CreateAsync` to complete but - in the meantime - the thread executing this method is free to handle other requests.

Here's some good [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: Also loving this answer, ashame I can't accept both, but thank you for your contribution! :)

Comment: @No1_Melman No problem - I've added a little extra detail that will hopefully clarify the use of `async` in this instance.